# how to establish a private network connection of AWS server to a remote IoT device running linux?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, iot, continuous-deployment

how to deploy a code to a remote IoT device running linux? Is there any zombie program to be written on the remote IoT device to establish a connection? Or is there any custom publisher subscriber shell script/python program needs to be handled at IoT device side? Is there any alternative web servers / Is it possible to deploy a code from gitlab to remote IoT device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS IoT Greengrass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/what-is-gg.html) is exactly the service you are looking for. You can set it up to be started with systemd and it will run a daemon that keeps your IoT device and the shadow device in sync. You can even deploy long-running lambda functions on your device that will only run locally (not in the cloud). All the deployment, secure connection, updating and offline handling is done by Greengrass.

I played with that and my Raspi with Sense HAT as my home office sensor. Now have a fancy dashboard of my room temperature, humidity and more... lots of fun.
You can get started [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html).